# How to make my bot leave a voice channel if there is no one in the channel

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots, internet-radio

I recently created a discord bot that plays radio, and I would like to know how to make sure that when there is no one the bot channeling it.

```
  if (oldState.channelID !==  oldState.guild.me.voice.channelID || newState.channel)
    return;

  // otherwise, check how many people are in the channel now
  if (!oldState.channel.members.size === 1) 
    setTimeout(() => { // if 1 (you), wait five minutes
      if (!oldState.channel.members.size === 1) // if there's still 1 member, 
         oldState.channel.leave(); // leave
     }, 10);
});
```

I tested this and it doesn't work, could someone help me? thx!

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```js
client.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldState, newState) => {
    if (oldState.channelID !==  oldState.guild.me.voice.channelID || newState.channel){
        return(0); //If it's not the channel the bot's playing in
    }
    if((oldState.channel.members.size -1) <= 1){
        //The bot's still in channel so it's never be zero
        //So we'll use <=1
        oldState.channel.leave();  //Leave the channel
    }
});
```

Put a `setTimeout` if you want to trigger this after some time
**Alternative:**

```js
client.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldState, newState) => {
    if (oldState.channelID !==  oldState.guild.me.voice.channelID || newState.channel){
        return(0); //If it's not the channel the bot's playing in
    }
    if(!oldState.channel.members.size -2){
        //The bot's still in channel so it's never be zero
        //We'll use -2 this time
        oldState.channel.leave();  //Leave the channel
    }
});
```

The comments should be self explanatory